# Avoid desktop login password when multiple desktops installed

Tags: login, password, desktop-environments

Ubuntu 18.04.  I am the sole user on a (VM) system, running the desktop.

When I started out with only the GNOME desktop installed as per default I got logged straight onto the desktop without any password.  This was also the case in prior versions of Ubuntu with Unity.  This is what I want.

A while ago I installed the Unity supplied with with 18.04 as an alternative if I want to play with it.  From that moment on I now get prompted for my password when I logon:

[image]

At the password prompt if instead I click on the "icon" it shows a choice of desktops.  Maybe that's why it wants to stop at a password prompt, so that I could choose:

[image]

(I don't really know why it shows `Unity (Default)` --- so far as I am aware(!), it still goes into GNOME.)

When I get to GNOME my desktop's **Users** settings still shows **Automatic Logon** is **ON**:

[image]

I would like simply to have it revert to going straight into GNOME without prompt/password like it used to.  Can I achieve that, without uninstalling Unity?

**EDIT**: Is there a file somewhere which lists these desktop choices for user to select from?  Perhaps if I commented out the other alternatives the chooser prompt would go away?

Comment: In gnome, one sets automatic login in the Settings. Perhaps, you also need to set this for your Unity session before this happens again. So look for the setting in Unity and change it there as well.

Comment: I have just edited to say when I get to GNOME I see that automatic logon is "on".  I never go into Unity.  I don't understand where you mean to do what?  It *seems* to me this behaviour must be *outside* of any desktop, as it's before the desktop gets selected??

Comment: You may be running lightdm now instead of gdm login manager. The latter may have been installed along with Unity. Try switching to gdm. You can remove Unity all together if you never go into unity.

Comment: @vanadium Thank you!  Is that `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`, or possibly `gdm3`, ?

Comment: Not sure myself: something like this indeed.

Comment: I tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`, and after selecting `gdm3` at the prompt, got `gdm.service is not active, cannot reload`.  This tells me I don't even understand what dm I am presently running, all I wanted to do is switch off the password prompt....